# How to install Jdk1.8.0_45 64 bit to Linux OS

Tags: software-installation, jdk, oracle

I am trying to download **jdk1.8.0_45** 64 bit on Linux OS , but I could not find it in Oracle site .. can you please share the path? I am not able to find the path in Oracle site.

Comment: Check here: https://www.java.com/en/download/linux_manual.jsp

Comment: Thank you for the link. But i could not find this particular version which iam looking for , jdk 1.8.0_45 can you please help me to find that in the same link which u sent.

Comment: Find it here: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/java-archive-javase8-2177648.html#sjre-8u45-oth-JPR AND to install here: https://www.tecmint.com/install-java-jdk-jre-in-linux/

Answer (score 0):

Here is the link to the download, http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk8-downloads-2133151.html.

Answer (score 0):

Download from archive page: ::
http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/java-archive-javase8-2177648.html